# How to access module info inside another module in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, nativescript

I'm working on a NativeScript app by using AngularJS2 & TypeScript. I've created one file `config.ts` for storing my API URL.

code for config.ts

```
export class Config {
  apiUrl = "https://incandescent-fire-8397.firebaseio.com/";
}
```

Then from an another file called `user.service.ts` I'm trying to access `apiUrl` value. But, don't know how to do it. Tried couple of permutation & combination but till now no luck.

Code for user.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "./user";
import Config = require("../config");

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    config: any;

    constructor() {
        this.config = new Config();
    }

    register(user: User) {
        alert("API url going to use is : "+this.config.apiUrl);
    }
}
```

Need some guidance.

Regards

**------Issue Fixed-------**

Updated the `user.service.ts` file

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "./user";
import {ConfigService} from "../config";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  apiUrl = "https://incandescent-fire-8397.firebaseio.com/";

  register(user: User,config:ConfigService) {
    //alert("About to register: " + user.email);
    alert("API url going to use is : "+config.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

Then, the module(`app.componets.ts`) from where I'm accessing the `register` method updated like this -

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {User} from "./shared/user/user";
import {UserService} from "./shared/user/user.service";
import {ConfigService} from "./shared/config";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  providers: [UserService, HTTP_PROVIDERS,ConfigService],
  templateUrl: "pages/login/login.html",
  styleUrls: ["pages/login/login-common.css", "pages/login/login.css"]
})

export class AppComponent {
    user: User;
    isLoggingIn = true;
    config:any;

    constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _configSerice:ConfigService) {
        this.user = new User();
        this.config = new ConfigService();
    }

    submit() {
        if (this.isLoggingIn) {
            this.login();
        } else {
            this.signUp();
        }
    }

    login() {
        // TODO: Define
        console.log('Clicked on Login button');

        firebase.init(<any>{
            persist: true // Allow disk persistence. Default false.
        }).then(
            function (instance) {
                console.log("firebase.init done");
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
            }
        );
    }

    signUp() {
        this._userService.register(this.user,this.config);
    }

    toggleDisplay() {
        this.isLoggingIn = !this.isLoggingIn;
    }
}
```

Don't know how much it's a right way to do. But, it's fixed the problem. Will appriciate a lot if someone know any better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you're initiating the Config module instead of the Config class inside it.

You can try adding the 'default' keyword to the "export class Config" line, or try initiating the config instance with "new Config.Config()".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give me some sample code? I'm really not getting how to deal with this typescript thing.

Comment: export default class Config {
  apiUrl = "https://incandescent-fire-8397.firebaseio.com/";
}